# await _unitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync(); is not saving changed to db

Tags: c#, asp.net, unity-container

I am working on asp.net mvc application using

```
Repository Pattern: https://genericunitofworkandrepositories.codeplex.com/ 
IoC: Unity Bootstrapper for ASP.NET MVC (Mandatory ) from NuGet
MVC Power Tools: https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvcPowerTools/
```

my view calls controller action like this:

```
  $.ajax({
                            url: '@Url.Action("SaveUserprofile")',
                            data: $('#UserProfileForm').serialize(),
                            success: function() {
                                $("#UserProfileForm").hide();
                                $("#PossitionForm").show();
                            }
                        })
```

and controller action is like this:

```
   private readonly IPublicUserService _publicUserService;
        private readonly IUnitOfWorkAsync _unitOfWork;

        public PublicUserController(IPublicUserService publicUserService, IUnitOfWorkAsync unitOfWork)
        {
            _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
            _publicUserService = publicUserService;
        }

  public async Task<bool> SaveUserprofile(UserProfile user)
        {
            var finaluser = _publicUserService.Add(user);
            await _unitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync();

            return true;
        }
```

and service interface is like  this:

```
 public interface IPublicUserService
    {
        UserProfile Add(UserProfile user);

    }
```

and service like this:

```
 private IRepository<UserProfile> _userRepository1;

        public PublicUserService(IRepository<UserProfile> userRepository)
        {
            _userRepository1 = userRepository;
        }


  public UserProfile Add(UserProfile user)
        {
            _userRepository1.Insert(user);
            return user;
        }
```

and generic repo like this:

```
 public interface IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class, IObjectState
    {
        TEntity Find(params object[] keyValues);
        IQueryable<TEntity> SelectQuery(string query, params object[] parameters);
        void Insert(TEntity entity);
        void InsertRange(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities);
        void InsertOrUpdateGraph(TEntity entity);
        void InsertGraphRange(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities);
        void Update(TEntity entity);
        void Delete(object id);
        void Delete(TEntity entity);
        IQueryFluent<TEntity> Query(IQueryObject<TEntity> queryObject);
        IQueryFluent<TEntity> Query(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> query);
        IQueryFluent<TEntity> Query();
        IQueryable<TEntity> Queryable();
        IRepository<T> GetRepository<T>() where T : class, IObjectState;
    }
```

and repo like this:

```
public virtual void Insert(TEntity entity)
{
    entity.ObjectState = ObjectState.Added;;
    _dbSet.Attach(entity);
    _context.SyncObjectState(entity);
}
```

and unityuconfig like this:

```
   public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
        {

            // TODO: Register your types here

            container.RegisterType<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>, UserStore<ApplicationUser>>();
            //container.RegisterType<DbContext, ApplicationDbContext>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());

            container.RegisterType<AccountController>(new InjectionConstructor());                  
            container.RegisterType<IUnitOfWorkAsync, UnitOfWork>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager());          
            container.RegisterType<IDataContextAsync, enterpriseContext>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager());
            container.RegisterType<IPublicUserService, PublicUserService>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
            container.RegisterType<IRepository<AspNetUser>, Repository<AspNetUser>>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
            container.RegisterType<IRepository<UserProfile>, Repository<UserProfile>>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());           
             container.RegisterType<IRepository<Region>, Repository<Region>>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager());
        }
```

but `await _unitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync();` is not saving changed to db. Please help to fix the issue.

Comment: There's a lot of code here, but none of it is relevant. Show what the `UnitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync()`'s implementation looks like.

Comment: `await _unitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync();` how are you verifying this? Have you used a database profiler to see what is actually happening?

Comment: savechangessync is like this  public int SaveChanges()
        {
            int result = _dataContext.SaveChanges();
            return result;
        }

Comment: I can' use profiler as database is on azure

Comment: Are you connecting to the database?

Comment: i am able to connect to Azure using sql server management studio

Comment: how can i add profiler to azure database ?